# Polynomial prove exercise

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$P(x)=x^n + a_1x^{n-1} +\dots+a_{n-1}x + 1$ with non-negative coefficients has $n$ real roots. Prove that $P(2)\ge 3n$ I don't have an idea how to do that, I'm in 4th grade high school, you don't have to solve it for me, I'd be just happy to get a clue how - + if someone could provide me with some sort of exercises like that with explanation I'd be happy thanks.

Comment: Can yourself read what you wrote?

Comment: Here is a guide to latex http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a_j\geq 0$ $(1\leq j\leq n-1)$, all zeros are negative. Hence
$$ P(x)=(x+r_1)\cdots (x+r_n)\qquad r_j>0, 1\leq j\leq n$$
and $r_1\cdots r_n=1$. It follows from this last equality that at least one $r_j$ is greater than or equal to $1$, which gives $r_1+\cdots+r_n\geq 1$.
It follows that
$$ P(2)=(2+r_1)\cdots (2+r_n)\geq 2^n+(r_1+\cdots+r_n)2^{n-1}+1\geq 2^n+2^{n-1}+1\geq 3n.$$

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Of course, you are right. I have fixed the answer. I hope that it is o.k. now.

Comment: Yep, looks good to me now!

Comment: thanks for answer it clears up everything a little bit for me - I understand concept of negative zero but I don't know how you concluded that all zeros are negative _aj≥0 (1≤j≤n−1)_ - and _P(x)=(x+r1)⋯(x+rn)_ where did you get that from?

Comment: @II Since all $a_j\geq 0$ one has $a_j x^j\geq 0$ if $x>0$. Of course, for $x>0$, also $x^n>0$ and $1>0$. We conclude that $P(x)$ is sum of nonnegative and positive numbers, so it is positive, i.e., there cannot be a zero on the positive part of the real line.

Comment: thanks, I'll definitely look at your answer again once I understand basic concepts of this kind of reasoning - do you know where can I learn that?

Comment: @II I am sorry, I don't know about suitable books in english... I hope that someone familiar with these thigs can recommend a good textbook.